# Set UINavigatioController tabBarItem on load

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my project, base view is a **UITabBarController**. It's connected to a **UISplitViewController** and a **UINavigationViewController**. I want to set **tabBarItem**'s icons programmatically. The first method I tried was setting them in the **UITabBarController**'s subclass. It didn't work. Next I tried to subclass each connected view and set their **tabBarItem** on **viewDidLoad** method of each view as follows:

[image]

```
//BaseSplitViewController.swift
class BaseSplitViewController: UISplitViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let searchIcon = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .search, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        let baseSplitViewBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: searchIcon, selectedImage: searchIcon)
        self.tabBarItem = baseSplitViewBarItem
    }
}

//FavoritesNavigationController.swift
class FavoritesNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let favIcon = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .star, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        let favViewBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Favorits", image: favIcon, selectedImage: favIcon)
        self.tabBarItem = favViewBarItem
    }
}
```

The default view to show up is the **splitView**. When the app is loaded, it shows the **tabBarItem** for **splitView** but until user does not click the other tab bar item, it's empty.

Before clicking the second tab bar item:

[image]

After clicking the second tab bar item:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second view is not loaded, after you actually show it. It's loaded in "lazy" mode - just when it's accessed for the first time.
It's an optimisation to not have a huge loading spike at application start, for things that are not visible at first.

Add your code to `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder` functions for both classes - it is called when your app is loaded for each of UIViewController inside a UITabBarViewController.
Going one step forward, just in case someone initialise your ViewControllers via code - it's best approach to have separate function that configures things like this always - despite of the initialisation method.

```
class BaseSplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureViewController()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureViewController()
    }

    private func configureViewController() {
        let searchIcon = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .search, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        let baseSplitViewBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: searchIcon, selectedImage: searchIcon)
        self.tabBarItem = baseSplitViewBarItem
    }
}
```